# How do I conduct a chi-squared test with one variable measured 0-7 and another variable with two categories?

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am looking at the relationship between Facebook usage and Political engagement. Political engagement is measured from 0-7 and Facebook usage is measured as "User" or "Non_User." How do I conduct a chisquared with this data? ... if this is the appropriate statistical method to use in the first place.

```
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="0. Zero days"] <- 0
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="1. One day"] <- 1
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="2. Two days"] <- 2
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="3. Three days"] <- 3
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="4. Four days"] <- 4
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="5. Five days"] <- 5
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="6. Six days"] <- 6
df$Political_engagement[df$V162174a=="7. Seven days"] <- 7

df$Facebook_usage[df$V162370=="1. Yes have a Facebook account I have used in the past month"] <- "User"
df$Facebook_usage[df$V162370=="2. Have a Facebook account but have not used it in past month"] <- "Non_user"
df$Facebook_usage[df$V162370=="3. No, do not have a Facebook account"] <- "Non_user"

df$User <- "User"
df$Non_user <- "Non_user"

table(df$Facebook_usage, df$Political_engagement)

chisq.test(df$User, df$Political_engagement, correct=FALSE)

Error in chisq.test(df$User, df$Political_engagement, correct = FALSE):
  'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

Comment: What's the output of the `table`? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But asking about appropriate uses of statistical methods is off topic for Stack Overflow. If you needs stats advice, you should seek help at [stats.se] instead.

Comment: But it also seems that you set everyone to a user with `df$User <- "User"`. You can't test for differences when every one of your rows has the same value for a given variable. Did you mean to use `df$Facebook_usage` in the `chisq.test` like you did in table rather than `df$User`?

Comment: I would like to see the different p values for the 'User' group and 'Non_user' group, that's why I didn't do df$Facebook_usage in the chisq.test

Comment: But you don't have a variable that tells whether or not someone is a user. you've hard coded the same value for `User` all rows in your data.frame. It's the `Facebook_usage` variable that you should be using for testing.

Comment: How would I make a variable that tells whether or not someone is a user? I though I did this with: `df$Facebook_usage[df$V162370=="1. Yes have a Facebook account I have used in the past month"] <- "User"
df$Facebook_usage[df$V162370=="2. Have a Facebook account but have not used it in past month"] <- "Non_user"
df$Facebook_usage[df$V162370=="3. No, do not have a Facebook account"] <- "Non_user"`

Comment: You did and you called it "Facebook_usage". Now you need to use that in your test! Use `chisq.test(df$Facebook_usage, df$Political_engagement, correct=FALSE)`

Comment: So with the result; X-squared = 11.503, df = 7, p-value = 0.1181... this is for just the 'User' group? *Edit* oh nevermind, I think I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question without reproducible code but a good approach is to consider using your `table(df$Facebook_usage, df$Political_engagement)` in the `chisq.test`. Consider:
`testtab<-table(df$Facebook_usage, df$Political_engagement)` and then `chisq.test(testtab)`